# Como implementar mongoose-paginate no Node Express?

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando implementar no meu projeto Node Express paginação numa lista de menu, e encontrei essa documentação logo baixo;

[MONGOOSE-PAGINATE](http://mongoose-paginate)

De acordo com as instruções primeiro instalei a lib com esse comando;

`npm install mongoose-paginate`

Em seguida configurei o meu model menu incluindo essa linha de código;

`var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');`

E esse também;

`schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);`

Como mostra abaixo;

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

const schema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true

    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    restaurantId: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true
    },

})

schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Menu', schema);
```

Em seguida criei o método que irá fazer a paginação dessa forma abaixo;

```
function getMenusPage (req, res) {
    Menus
    .find({ }, { page: 3, limit: 5 }, function(err, menu)  {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error na solicitação'
            });
        }else{
            if(!menu){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'Não existe nenhum menu nesse registro'
                });
            }else{
                res.status(200).send({
                    menu
                });
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Não está gerando erro no código e nem no console, o que gostaria de saber é como irei testar no **Postman** para saber se a implementação está correta?

Eu tentei fazer dessa forma

`router.get('/menuspage', controller.getMenusPage);`

Com essa URL;

`http://localhost:3000/menuspage`

Mas tive o erro **404**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia wladyband
Eu aconselhava a fazeres a paginação com o modulo [api-query-params](https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-query-params)
E muito facil de usar e podes adaptar ao projeto facilmente.
Para além da paginação ainda podes fazer filtros.
Ex:
importas o modulo

```
var aqp = require('api-query-params');
```

depois imagina que queres listar uma coleção completa.
Ex:
//List All Providers

```
exports.list_all_dataProviders = async (req, res) => {

  const { filter, skip, limit, sort, projection } = aqp(req.query);
  Provider
    .find(filter)
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(limit)
    .sort(sort)
    .select(projection)
    .exec(async (err, result) => {

      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).jsonp({message:"There was an internal error listing all the providers " + err});
      }

      let count = await Provider.find().count()


      res.status(200).jsonp({
        limit: limit,
        skip: skip,
        total: count,
        data: result
      });
    });

};
```

para a paginação usas o skip e o limit .
No entanto penso que o que te está a faltar se quiseres manter o mongoose paginate é chamar o metodo assim.

```
var Menu= mongoose.model('Menu',  schema);
Menu.paginate();
```

e ai deves ter acesso aos métodos disponiveis.

[Mongoose-paginate-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate)
Espero que tenha ajudado , alguma duvida dispoe

Comment: muito obrigado pegou, valeu mesmo, isso é um achado! hahahahaha, MUITO OBRIGADO.

Comment: Se tem mais um detalhe, ele trouce o  data e total, porém não trouce o `limit` e o `skip` , eu preciso desse dois  para completar a implementação que vou fazer no Front-end

Comment: Eu acho que já entende porque ele não trouce.

Comment: E só colocar assim e tem acesso `http://localhost:3000/menuspage?skip=1&limit=4` gostei muito dessa lib.

Comment: sim e isso mesmo. E ainda podes usar filtros como por queres uma listagem so com nomes se puseres no filter nomes ele vai listar todos os nomes etc :D

Comment: Show de bola kkkk

Comment: Se você não se incomodar gostaria de tirar mais uma dúvida! como ficaria o método se caso eu fosse realizar um filtro assim?    `http://localhost:3000/menu?description=Coberto`, eu mencionei `Coberto`, mas poderia ser qualquer valor na consulta

Comment: Para filtrar podes usar várias formas: Por exemplo se quiseres um campo do objecto json podes usar as Projections: e fazes a query assim : `http://localhost:3000/menu?fields=coberto` ou se quiseres fazer um filtro podes fazer assim , neste exemplo tens todos os campos que podes utilizar `status=sent&timestamp>2016-01-01&author.firstName=/john/i*&limit=100&skip=50&sort=-timestamp&fields=id'` desde o **status** até ao **/i** é aplicado o filtro. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: é que mesmo com as orientações com  Projections ou Filter não tive sucesso.

Comment: eles tem de ser implementados por ordem. Ve este exemplo que foi implementado por mim. Está nesta api! No entanto aconselho-te a usar sempre um limit porque são muitos dados para devolver. Não na parte dos dataProviders mas nas Theses. https://masterplat.herokuapp.com/api-docs/

Comment: eu descobri que se eu fizer assim o  método se comporta do jeito que eu quero `http://localhost:3000/menu?description=/coberto/i` , com isso resolvi em partes meu problema.